# Can GoogleFinance function produce an analyst recommendation?

Tags: google-finance

Google Sheets has a very useful function called [`GoogleFinance`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281).

`GoogleFinance` can produce a lot of information about a stock. For example, price, high, low, volume, etc.

Can this function be used to produce an analyst recommendation for stocks?

An example of an analyst recommendation can be seen here: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/goog/analystestimates

Comment: What do you think "analyst recommendation" means? do you think that Google has analysts who do this?

Comment: If GoogleSheets has a `random()` function, it can probably be used to match most analysts' recommendations :-)

Comment: No idea what you mean.  Analyst recommendation is just another Analytical data like price, volume. I used to work for Bloomberg and Bloomberg API provide this analysis for every ticker.

Comment: Example : https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/goog/analystestimates

Comment: An analyst recommendation is a recommendation provided by an analyst; a human being who works out statistically by various means whether the stock is under- over- or fairly priced. Most news sources' version of this is an average of a number of investment banks' and analytics companies recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An analyst recommendation is a recommendation provided by an analyst; a human being who works out statistically by various means whether the stock is under- over- or fairly priced. Most news sources' version of this is an average of a number of investment banks' and analytics companies' recommendations.

Google finance neither has the analysts nor the aggregation to provide this.